# Does experimental ES Module loading in NodeJS support importing named exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, ecmascript-6

See the following `import`:

```
import { publishObjectAsync, consumeObjectsAsync, createChannelAsync } from "../shared/messaging/rabbitmq"
```

Which produces this error:

> SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named
>   'publishObjectAsync'

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, sorry, It was my fault but I believe that it's worth the effort providing my own answer so others may encounter the same problem and they can get a hint!

The code file extensions within `/shared` weren't renamed to `.mjs`!!!!!

So, if you find this issue you should check if the export exists in the target module or if the imported module has the Michael Jackson file extension (.mjs).

That was the issue. It supports alisaes all the way!

Comment: Does that mean the target file was being processed with Babel or something you mean? Or was it ES6 import syntax in a `.js` file? Wouldn't that throw a syntax error?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Not anymore, I'm using `--experimental-modules`. It's Node's native ES2015 modules.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yeah you know I was using Babel, but I switched to `--experimental-modules` and my fault was I renamed all file extensions to `.mjs` but I forgot to do it in a dependent project so I was loading CJS modules from ES modules.

Comment: Yeah I'm just confused because you said `import { publishObjectAsync } from` worked, which shouldn't be the case for CommonJS. Was that also not working?

Comment: @loganfsmyth If the imported module is CJS it won't work with named imports

Comment: Right so the `If I remove aliases ... it'll work flawlessly` in the question was incorrect. Sounds like we should edit this question to just talk about named exports and not aliases, since the aliases weren't actually the issue.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Is it fine now?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you used for aliases is right - so I would assume experimental ES Module loading does not support importing specific exports with aliases.

You could try to load all exports with an alias, though:

```
import * as rabbitmq from "rabbitmq";

export const createChannelAsync = () => rabbitmq.createChannelAsync(createConnectionAsync);
```

Or you could try if the export syntax supports aliases.

```
export { name1 as default, … };
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export for further information on the syntax.

Comment: Appears to be the case. Here's [the commit](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/c8a389e19f172edbada83f59944cad7cc802d9d5) which has test cases for `import *` and `import default` but I don't see one for `import { x as y }` which presumably backs up the assumption that this isn't implemented as yet

Comment: See my own answer, thank you anyway for the effort! And yeah, an aliased wildcard import would've been the workaround.